# Looking for a specific word for anticipating in advance

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's a word to describe *anticipating in advance*?

> I propose we meet next month __________ any problems I may encounter with obtaining visa.

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re trying to say.  What leaps to mind for your  sentence is ***barring***  but that doesn’t mean “anticipating in advance”.

Comment: _Anticipate_ already means ‘in advance’. I don’t quite see what you’re looking for here either.

Comment: Agree with @Jim - barring seems to be the word you are looking for.

Comment: If you mean it's the *problems* that are anticipated, then "I propose we meet next month (*about / to discuss*) [those problems] I encounter with obtaining [a] visa." But that has nothing to do with a word other than *anticipating*.

Answer (score 1):

I too favor **barring** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bar)

> a. To prohibit or prevent (someone) from doing something: Failing the
>   eye exam barred him from driving. b. To prohibit (an action):

The anticipation is already in your sentence:  *we meet next month*.
The potential caveats are implied by **barring**.

As in:

'I propose we meet next month **barring** any problems I may encounter with Obtaining a visa.

and

> An extra point would send it to OT and barring a tie, just about
>   guarantee the over to hit. Golf Digest Oct 21, 2018

Answer (score 0):

your whole sentence is a bit off. you might try instead:

*I see no problems coming up* with obtaining the visa.

*I see no reason why (Subject Pronoun) won't* obtain the visa.

*There shouldn't be any problems* with *getting* the visa.

Comment: I think OP’s intent here is:  “I’ve scheduled a meeting for next month because I’m sure I’m going to run into some problems getting my visa and I want to make sure I have some time on your calendar to discuss them. And if there aren’t any we can just cancel it.